# While loop won't run in Python (beginner)?

Tags: python, while-loop

For some reason I'm having trouble getting my program to run a while loop.
No error messages, just that it stops the program. I tried having it print "hi" as the first instruction, but it didn't, so I know it's not even running the loop. Here's a bit of code (Note: The testing for correct values works fine, but the loop won't use these correct values!)

```
print "current letter value:", letter_value

print "letter:", letter

print "number:", number

while letter!="$" and number<=5 and number>=1:
    print "hi"
```

//all the stuff in here

I know it *should* be an infinite loop, but it won't run at all!
Input:
letter is 'A'
letter_value is 1
numberis 1
My loop ought to test to make sure that letter isn't $ and that the number is <=5 and number >=1

Comment: show us in which case it is not working (works fine with me)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you didn't give the print out for letter and number, it could be that the "number" is actually a string?

Comment: thanks! that seems to be it! I changed it to number=int(raw_input())

Comment: @MaddyByahoo: and that's why you should always post a *complete* example.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is fine. Without seeing all of your code, I generically recommend that you might want to make sure there aren't any invisible whitespace characters that are breaking you out of the loop unexpectedly. Also verify that 'letter' and 'number' are have values that will make the while conditions happy (e.g., if 'number' is 0, then it won't kick off).